# How to print values in GUI from image in python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, gui-builder

I'm new in GUI developing.Here i'hv created two GUI, one for taking photo and another for showing features.so,i'hv used two functions.but i don't know some things.Now i need two kinds of help from you.
1)what is the command for printing float value in GUI(not on console)? 
2)How to calculate the value of mean,variance ,s.d. etc from a image and how to pass those values from one function to another function?

```
 import tkinter as tk
 from tkinter.filedialog 
 import askopenfilename
 import shutil
 import os
 from PIL import Image, ImageTk

 window = tk.Tk()

 window.title(" ")

  window.geometry("500x510")
  window.configure(background ="lightgreen")
  title = tk.Label(text="Click below to choose picture for testing disease....", background = "lightgreen", fg="Brown", font=("", 15))
  title.grid()
 def feature():
    window.destroy()
    window1 = tk.Tk()

    window1.title(" ")

    window1.geometry("650x510")
                      window1.configure(background="lightgreen")

      def exit():
             window1.destroy()
    #i want to print some features of image e.g. Mean, variance,s.d. Etc.
      button = tk.Button(text="Exit", command=exit)
      button.grid(column=0, row=9, padx=20, pady=20)

      window1.mainloop()


def openphoto():
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

    dirPath = " "
    fileList = os.listdir(dirPath)
    for fileName in fileList:
         os.remove(dirPath + "/" + fileName)

          fileName = askopenfilename(initialdir='', title='Select image for analysis ',
                       filetypes=[('image files', '.jpg')])
          dst = " "
          shutil.copy(fileName, dst)
          #this is the image
          Photo = Image.open(fileName)

          render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo)
          img = tk.Label(image=render, height="250", width="500")
          img.image = render
          img.place(x=0, y=0)
          img.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady = 10)
          title.destroy()
          button1.destroy()
          button2 = tk.Button(text="Analyse Image", command=feature)
         button2.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=10, pady = 10)
 button1 = tk.Button(text="Get Photo", command = openphoto)
 button1.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady = 10)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I took some more time to look into it.
Concerning the calculation of the values, your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54425336/how-can-i-print-some-features-in-python-opencv-gui/54428756?noredirect=1#comment95694951_54428756) did that correct, however the variables needed to be accessible globally. Concerning the displaying of a text, you have to add a tkinter text widget. If you want to add more calculated values, just google for numpy + 'value your want'.

I've taken your code and created a working example, see the code below. Note that I removed some stuff that wasn't neede for the example, so copy the lines you need to your own code. Also check out [this reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text.html) for the text widget.

Result:

[image]

Code:
Note: I created 2 text widgets deliberately, to show 2 ways of implementing multiple texts

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import shutil
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window = tk.Tk()

window.title(" ")

window.geometry("500x510")
window.configure(background ="lightgreen")
title = tk.Label(text="Click below to choose picture for testing disease....", background = "lightgreen", fg="Brown", font=("", 15))
title.grid()

def feature():
    window.destroy()
    window1 = tk.Tk()
    window1.title(" ")

    ### create a text widget, place it in window1 and insert the text
    width_txt = tk.Text(window1, height=2, width=30, fg="RED", background = "lightgreen", relief="flat")
    width_txt.grid(column=0, row=0)
    width_txt.insert(tk.END, "Width: " + str(width))

    height_txt = tk.Text(window1, height=2, width=30, fg="RED", background = "lightgreen", relief="flat")
    height_txt.grid(column=0, row=1)
    height_txt.insert(tk.END, "Height: " + str(height) + "\nMean: " + str(mean))


    window1.geometry("650x510")
    window1.configure(background="lightgreen")

def openphoto():

    ### this line makes the variables accessible everywhere
    global width,height, mean
    import numpy as np

    fileName = askopenfilename(initialdir='', title='Select image for analysis ',
                filetypes=[('image files', '.jpg')])
    photo = Image.open(fileName)

    #### calculate values 
    height = np.size(photo, 0)
    width = np.size(photo, 1)
    mean = np.mean(photo)


    render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo)
    img = tk.Label(image=render, height="250", width="500")
    img.image = render
    img.place(x=0, y=0)
    img.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady = 10)
    title.destroy()
    button1.destroy()
    button2 = tk.Button(text="Analyse Image", command=feature)
    button2.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=10, pady = 10)

button1 = tk.Button(text="Get Photo", command = openphoto)
button1.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady = 10)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks ...Now it's working well with a small problem.
Can u give me ur email or fb id link ?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Can u help me of drawing ROC,TPR,FPR for this code?

Comment: I have never done that, but check out this [tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/how-to-embed-matplotlib-graph-tkinter-gui/). If you get stuck you can always open a new question. Good luck!

Comment: Thank u very much❤️